# Datatable Requested unknown parameter '1' for row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I have the following Datatable

```
<br><button id="addRow">Add New Row</button><br>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover "  id="example" cellSpacing=0 width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Image</th>
                                <th>number</th>
                                <th>Creation_date</th>
                                <th>ei</th>
                                <th>name</th>
                                <th>profit</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <?php
                            foreach ( $data_req_table as $k => $v ) :
                        ?>
                        <tr style="text-align: center;">
                            <td>
                                   <img      width="100px"
                                    data-original="image.jpg"
                                    src="image.jpg"
                                     />
                            </td>
                            <td><? echo $v['number']; ?></td>
                            <td><? echo $v['creationdate']; ?></td>
                            <td><? echo $v['ei']; ?></td>
                            <td><? echo $v['name']; ?></td>
                            <td><? echo $v['profit']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                            endforeach;
                        ?>
                    </table>
```

on which I add rows trough a Jquery - Ajax script. following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            debugger;
                            var t = $('#example').DataTable({ 
                                                                "searching": true, 
                                                                //"paging": true, 
                                                                "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]], 
                                                                aLengthMenu: [
                                                                    [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
                                                                    [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
                                                                ], iDisplayLength: -1
                                                            });
                            var counter = 1;
                            $('#addRow').on('click', function ciicici() {
                            var now = new Date();
                            var now = now.toMysqlFormat();
                            var tii = new Date();
                            tii.setSeconds(tii.getSeconds() - 15);
                            var tii = tii.toMysqlFormat();
                            //alert(tii);
                             $.post( "sql.php", {  timing: now,seconding: tii  })//.done({});
                             .done(function( data ) { 

                                var dataParts = data.split("##")
                                var lenghtylenght = dataParts.length;

                                for (i = 0; i <= lenghtylenght; i++) { 
                                    var dataPart = dataParts[i];
                                    var splitData = dataPart.split("///");
                                    t.row.add([
                                        splitData[0], 
                                        splitData[1], 
                                        splitData[2], 
                                        splitData[3], 
                                        splitData[4], 
                                        splitData[5]
                                    ]).draw();
                                    alert('done');
                                }
                                counter++;
                                }); 
                                //setTimeout(function(){ciicici();}, 15000);
                            });
                            $('#addRow').click();
                        });
                    </script>
```

and the php  being

```
$ippi = 0;
foreach ( $data_rreq as $k => $v ) : //data_rreq is the pdo fetched array
    $ippi++;
    echo "<td><img width='100px' src='image.jpg' /></td>".'///';
    echo '<td>'.$v['number'].'</td>'.'///';
    echo '<td>'.$v['creationdate'].'</td>'.'///';
    echo '<td>'.$v['ei'].'</td>'.'///';
    echo '<td>'.$v['name'].'</td>'.'///';
    echo '<td>'.$v['profit'].'</td>';

    if($ippi < $len){
    echo "##";
    }
endforeach;
```

The code works but I have 2 problems :

1) Datatable problem, everytime a row is automatically added, I get an error : Requested unknown parameter '1' for row ... . It looks like it loops once too much, it doesn't find any results and it has an error. My datatable reference being the following :

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

2) And then I wanted to ask wether there is a way to avoid using the split function to puss 5 different parameters to a request, using may be some sort of json encoded arrays.

markoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your loop need to be patched:

```
for (i = 0; i <= lenghtylenght; i++)
```

Replace with:

```
for (i = 0; i < lenghtylenght; i++)
```

Else you will go outofindex.

Comment: Yes, or just `for (var i=0; i<dataParts.length; i++)` we really not gaining anything by using a lookup variable here, and to the worse `i` is never declared at all.  Also OP should consider using wellformed markup and wrap the rows into a `<tbody>` section.